# How do I change the icon on an external drive?

Tags: external-disk, icon, bug

How do I change the icon on an external drive? I have a Samsung T5 SSD but following the instructions (copy from source Get Info dialog, and paste into destination Get Info dialog) has no effect and no feedback. This used to work in the past, but since then I've upgraded to newer external drives (and have updated macOS several times). Has something changed that now makes this impossible?

I've tried this now with several drives (various hardware) and am unable to change the icon on any of them. This used to work before (1) updating macOS and (2) reformatting the drives with APFS/GUID. Has one of those changes made it impossible to change the icon on external drives?

Comment: You say you used copy/paste, but did you also try drag/drop? If that does not work, then did you try copying the hidden `.VolumeIcon.icns` file from one drive to the other? (You can press `Shift + ⌘ + .` to view hidden files in the Finder.)

Comment: @DavidAnderson None of the usual methods work. This appears to be a big in Catalina (and it appears that I was lucky, many users report also _losing all_ of their existing icon customizations).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
As [@David Anderson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson) mentioned, the icon is stored in `.VolumeIcon.icns` in the root of the external drive. This is a hidden file by default, so press `⌘ + Shift + .` to see hidden files. By default, the `.VolumeIcon.icns` file does not exist, and if it does, the icon in the file will be used.

If you want to see all default icon files for modification purposes, go to `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`. Then, you can move or modify any icon of your choosing to the drive.

---

Changing the icon of external drives still works on macOS. Here are the steps to do so.

1. Download an image to your computer
2. Open the image with `Preview.app`
3. Press `⌘ + C` to copy the image to your clipboard
4. Select your external drive (Go to finder then `Shift + ⌘ + C` to see your external drives)
5. Select your drive and press `⌘ + I`
6. Right-click the icon in the upper-left-hand corner of the popup window
7. Press `⌘ + V` to paste the image to the drive

Comment: I am not sure how this differs from what method posted in the OP's question, but did find the `Shift + ⌘ + C` step useful.

Comment: This doesn't work. The issue is that the normal method does not work for me. Does this still work on APFS/GUID drives? It doesn't seem to.

Comment: Check if you have write access to the drive. If so, this could be caused by a bug that does not update the drive icon initially when it is changed through this method. Follow the method, then open the root of the drive and press `⌘ + Shift + .` to see hidden files. There should be a `.VolumeIcon.icns` file located here with the pasted image. If this is correct, log out then restart your computer and the icon should appear.